# Mysql: Interval time of a day and a half

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking for ways to do it from 6:00pm yesterday and on till the next day at 8:00am to report back. Currently, this just gives me all of yesterdays and today's report.

That's my code for reporting on activities that haven't completed.

```
and A.scheduled_start > DATE_FORMAT(date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 36 HOUR), '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59') 
and A.status != 'completed'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `date_format`? Isn't `scheduled_start` a date/time/timestamp column? It should be.

Comment: Scheduled_start is in a date format

Comment: So, is it a date colum or a char/varchar/text column? If the latter, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE   a.scheduled_start >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 HOUR
        AND a.scheduled_start < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 8 HOUR
        AND a.status <> 'completed'
```

Comment: Hmm.. didn't quite work. Here is my entire line.  `WHERE (1 = 1)`   `and user_name='sg'`
`and A.scheduled_start > DATE_FORMAT(date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 2 DAY), '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')`
`and A.status != 'completed'`

Comment: My mistake, it was all a big syntax error. Thanks for the help.